# Force duplicate resource file requests to make separate HTTP requests?

Tags: php, http, header, request, httprequest

I realize this is generally a bad idea, but I want each duplicate file resource link on a site to make a separate HTTP request.

Let's say there's some imgs that requests a file, like so:

```
<img src="http://example.com">
<img src="http://example.com">
<img src="http://example.com">
```

*Typically, the browser would make only one request for http://example.com, which is great for performance and makes a lot of sense!*

I'd like the browser to make **3 individual requests**, each and every time http://example.com shows up.

By the way, the page I'm linking to is a PHP redirect file, so maybe that opens up some possibilities? It'd be great, if I could just add some headers to the PHP file, but I don't know if that's feasible (just started with PHP so I'm admittedly naive).

Any info at all is welcome, thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want execute php file more than one time without browse cached, you can add param to link: example.com?time=<?=random_string?>

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to get the same effect without changing the original link?

Answer (score 0):

This is 3 separated requests.

```
<img src="http://example.com?t=1234">
<img src="http://example.com?t=2324">
<img src="http://example.com?t=4355545">
```

For generate string random: (in PHP)

```
<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg?t=<?=uniqid()?>">
```

And browser is not cached your image